# How to install odoo 12 enterprise edition in docker?

Tags: odoo

Please I need to run container odoo 12 (entreprise edition) , but not community edition, I try to do:

```
docker run -p 9012:8069 -itd -v /volumes/odoo:/mnt/extra-addons --name od1 --link pg1:db -t odoo:12
```

i have tested also:

```
docker run -p 9012:8069 -itd -v /volumes/odoo:/mnt/extra-addons --name od1 --link pg1:db -t odoo
```

But when I go to browser, I find that odoo is community version ! How to have odoo enterprise edition (version 12)?

Answer (score 2):

add another volume to your container for example `-v ./config:/etc/odoo` and within this directory add config file `odoo.conf` with `addons_path` set to a list containing `/mnt/extra-addons` in the list. To initialize odoo with enterprise edition, `addons_path` list must contain the path to the `enterprise` addons directory.

Comment: For the less-than-expert Odoo installers:  Mounting the volumes for modules ensures that they are available to Odoo.  Odoo will not use them until you tell odoo.conf (or your command line) which modules to run.